# Handling a Context Menu when not selecting an item

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, contextmenu

I need help with an event that I couldn't handle myself. I have a Context Menu attached to a TextView in a Fragment which works perfectly. I open the menu with `onCreateContextMenu`, and then I handle the events with `onContextItemSelected`. 
When I open the menu, I want to show an element in addition to the menu, like the pencil in this photo:

[image]

my issue is this: when I choose nothing from the menu, or press the *back* button, the element still shows. 
how can I make it disappear at the same time the menu does?

Thanks in advance.

edit: when I choose an item from the menu, the pencil disappears.

Comment: post your onContextItemSelected

Comment: Have you come across the `onContextMenuClosed()` method?

Comment: I haven't. the Android Studio doesn't look familiar with this method. Maybe because I try to do it inside the Fragment class, and not within the Activity class?

Comment: when I think about it once again. should I use an interface in my fragment, and use it as a callback to the activity, which will handle ```onContextMenuClosed()```?

Comment: Yeah, that is an `Activity` method, one for which `Fragment` does not have an equivalent, unfortunately. However, context menus in a `Fragment` will cause `onContextMenuClosed()` to run in the `Activity`, so you could do something like is shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16848058). An interface might be handy if you have multiple such `Fragment`s, but you could just call the method directly in that one `Fragment`, if that's the only one.

Comment: Thank you Mike, this post fixed my problem.

Comment: @kelvin Please feel free to edit your answer with a more complete example and/or explanation, if you'd care to. I wouldn't feel right putting my words into someone else's post. Ori is more than welcome to accept your answer, if they'd like, to show that this question has been resolved. Thanks, though. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try onContextMenuClosed method

```
 @Override
public void onContextMenuClosed(@NonNull Menu menu) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onContextMenuClosed(menu);
}
```